# Easiest way to collect SOAP response data

Tags: java, python, soap

Good day,

There is a SOAP interface which returns the data I need. The request passes initial parameters to the server, and returns a data set. I need to collect hundreds of data sets with different parameters, store them in an array and then iterate through it. This process may need to be repeated every few weeks.

I found that SoapUI can retrieve the datasets one by one, but this means a lot of manual work. In my experience SoapUI also freezes every 30 minutes or so, especially if large datasets are involved. I spent a few days retrieving the data via SoapUI, copypasting the responses into array and then iterating through it with Javascript - but this approach seems very inefficient.

I never worked with SOAP before this - so most of the online tutorials fly over my head. SoapUI is quick and easy, but doesn't seem suitable for automatically retrieving large quantities of data. I don't have a huge preference for a programming language - whatever is simplest to implement is fine with me. I'd be perfectly happy if the response comes in an XML that's simply in a string format - it can then be parsed with regex, I know how to do this. I have a bit of experience with java and python though, if that helps. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [Zeep](http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/), a Python SOAP client.

The response object you’ll get back can be accessed just like a dictionary, you can do things like response['key']. You can also serialize zeep objects to native python data structures.